# Get First Element of JsonConvert results?

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using Riot's API here: https://developer.riotgames.com/api/methods#!/909/3144

That request allows you to give a comma-delimited list of usernames and returns user information.

I am executing my code as follows:

```
string getUrl = "https://" + this.regionID + ".api.pvp.net/api/lol/" + this.regionID +
    "/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" + summoner.Text + "?api_key=" + this.apiKey;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

This returns the results as follows:

```
{
   "prorate": {
      "id": 20335410,
      "name": "ProRate",
      "profileIconId": 693,
      "revisionDate": 1420864656000,
      "summonerLevel": 30
   },
   "jaxelrod": {
      "id": 31034983,
      "name": "Jaxelrod",
      "profileIconId": 744,
      "revisionDate": 1420999923000,
      "summonerLevel": 30
   }
}
```

Now, lets say I want to get the ID of the first user returned in the list. I know I can do so using the following code:

```
json.prorate.id.ToString();
```

However, I wont necessarily know the index of the first element in the list. In this specific case, its `prorate`, but it could be something different on each call. Is there a call I could make to simply retrieve the first element of the array? Something like `json.First().id.ToString()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use dynamic

```
var userList  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < Dictionary<string, User>>(json);

public class User
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int profileIconId { get; set; }
    public long revisionDate { get; set; }
    public int summonerLevel { get; set; }
}
```

You can also use Linq

```
var id = JObject.Parse(json).Children().First().Values<int>("id").First();
```

Comment: But what if Riot changes the API? Wont that break things?

Comment: Plus, it kind of seems pointless to create a class for all this when all I need is a single piece of data... then I throw out and never use the rest of it every again.

Comment: Also, getting an error `The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments.`